# Xcode project, based on static framework without AppDelegate. How to add AppDelegate?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have Xcode project, that don't have any classes. It just run static framework from main.m:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    start(argc, argv);
}
```

How I can add for example push notifications to this project ?
Im able to add my own classes and execute a code inside  +(void)load, that will be launched before main.m
But I am unable to run this code as a parallel thread.

May be I should create AppDelegate, but how to run this framework from AppDelegate ?

-alex

Comment: Why don't you just create a new UI project from template and copy/link your framework to it?

Comment: I know only, how to start this framework from main.m and don't know, how to run it from UI project

Comment: Looks like I need to find a way to run my static framework from an AppDelegate. How this can be done ? Do I need to disassemble framework to find some entry points/parameters ? Or it's not possible beyond the main.m ?